# wxwidgets pubsub -- Detect which object sent message

Tags: python, model-view-controller, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am building a GUI with wxPython and attempting to stay true to the MVC by keeping my view in the dark from my model. I am using the pubsub library to send messages from the model which the controller will subscribe to and then update the view as necessary.

I do have a complication however. My model has a list of instances of the same object, and each object will need to send its own health and status status update message. Each object has its own panel in the view as shown below.

[image: dining philosopher status table]

My controller has a list of the objects:

```
kierkegaard   = PhilosophersWithMetaData("Soren Kierkegaard", "thumbnails/kierkegaard.jpg", forks[0], forks[4])
lewis         = PhilosophersWithMetaData("C.S. Lewis", "thumbnails/lewis.jpg", forks[1], forks[0])
dostoevsky    = PhilosophersWithMetaData("Fyodor Dostoevsky", "thumbnails/dostoevsky.jpg", forks[2], forks[1])
descartes     = PhilosophersWithMetaData("Rene Descartes", "thumbnails/descartes.jpg", forks[3], forks[2])
kant          = PhilosophersWithMetaData("Immanuel Kant", "thumbnails/kant.jpg", forks[4], forks[3])

philosopher_list = [kierkegaard, lewis, dostoevsky, descartes, kant]
```

And each Philosopher in the model has:

```
def changeState(self, new_state):
    self.state = new_state
    pub.sendMessage("STATE_CHANGED", self.state)
```

My question is, how do I know which object sent the message so I can update the correct panel? I will need a index or object to reference so I can pass the update onto the view. Is there a "MVC approved" way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put extra arguments on the

`Publisher.sendMessage("someMessage",["some_argument",1])`

In this case you would do

```
Publisher.sendMessage("someMessage",self)
...
Publisher.subscribe(self.MyPubsubListenerForSomeMessage,"someMessage")
... 
def MyPubsubListenterForSomeMessage(self,e):
    print e.data
```

Comment: So simple, should have thought of that. Thanks so much.

Comment: But isn't this the wrong way round? Send the message to a global instance, which distributes it to all listeners (for this message), and each listener decides whether to react on the message. From Smalltalk, I am used to a local mechanism: Each model keeps a list of interested observers, and sends messages only to them. Is implemented as part of a "Model" class to be used in MVC, and the controller just registers as interested (in Smalltalk, as a "dependent") with the model object. Any idea why we use a global, less performant scheme here? Thanks

Comment: there are lots of different event types... this is specifically pubsub's behavior.  normal wx.EVT_XXXX get bound only by interested parties.  think of pubsub as some global object that has infinite eventTypes,  interested parties tell it they want to subscribe to some "event"(really just a string and what method will be called with it.) ... edited my answer to include the event subscription